# JSON-Server doesn't update my .json file after fetching some new data

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Currently I'm working on little app that's using JSON server but I have a little problem. Objects I'm working with consist of id, name, and complete fields like this {"id": ,"name": ,"complete": }. Fetching data from the server works fine but putting some new data inside it doesn't work. My code looks like this:

```
export const addNewItem = (newItem) =>{
  return fetch(myUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application-json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newItem)
  }).then(res => res.json())
 }
```

After adding new item to my server there only id in it ({"id": some new id}. The name and complete fields are gone. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: few questions. where do you store your json data? what is your newItem? can you share related server side code?

Comment: You've got a typo on your `Content-Type` value... it should also be "application/json".

Comment: My json data is stored in db.json file. newItem is.....new object that matches the pattern of already stored objects. There's no server side code :) I use https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: yeah.... getting rid of that typo solved the problem. Thanks :)